# How to extract list from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have list of tuples like this:

```
data = [(4, [1, 2]),
 (10, [3, 13]),
 (9, [14, 6]),
 (10, [7, 5]),
 (19, [2, 7]),
 (15, [15, 5]),
 (21, [9, 12]),
 (250, [11, 11]),
 (25, [5, 5]),
 (100, [2, 10]),
 (120, [8, 11]),
]
```

How to get three separate lists from it without using loop and iteration, like :

```
a = [4,10,9,19,...]
b = [1,3,14,7,2,...]
c = [2,13,6,5,7,...]
```

My attempt with loop

```py
a = []
b = []
c = []

for t in data:
  a.append(t[0])
  b.append(t[1][0])
  c.append(t[1][1])
```

Comment: Whats wrong with using a loop?

Comment: you basically want to flatten and zip.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Isn't this unzipping?

Comment: @Barmar sure, but you can use `zip` to unzip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to flatten and "unzip":

```
>>> def flatten(row):
...     a,[b,c] = row
...     return a,b,c
...
>>> data = [(4, [1, 2]),
 (10, [3, 13]),
 (9, [14, 6]),
 (10, [7, 5]),
 (19, [2, 7]),
 (15, [15, 5]),
 (21, [9, 12]),
 (250, [11, 11]),
 (25, [5, 5]),
 (100, [2, 10]),
 (120, [8, 11]),
]
>>> a,b,c = zip(*map(flatten, data))
>>> a
(4, 10, 9, 10, 19, 15, 21, 250, 25, 100, 120)
>>> b
(1, 3, 14, 7, 2, 15, 9, 11, 5, 2, 8)
>>> c
(2, 13, 6, 5, 7, 5, 12, 11, 5, 10, 11)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
a, b, c = zip(*[(a,b,c) for a, [b, c] in data])
```

But honestly, the loop you have is fine. I would probably just use that,but clean it up like this:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
for i, (j, k) in data:
    a.append(i)
    b.append(j)
    c.append(k)
```

**EDIT**

Here are some timings, I'll use the list-comprehension version, because it should be faster than using `map` (no repeated function-call overhead):

```
>>> def with_unzip(data):
...     a,b,c =  zip(*((a,b,c) for a,[b,c] in data))
...     return a,b,c
...
>>> def with_loop(data):
...     a = []
...     b = []
...     c = []
...     for i, [j, k] in data:
...         a.append(i)
...         b.append(j)
...         c.append(k)
...     return a,b,c
...
```

Now, let's setup an appreciably large dataset to test this with:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> data_big  = data * 10_000
>>> print(f'{len(data_big):,d}')
110,000    
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : with_unzip(data_big), number=100)
2.4092896859999655
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : with_loop(data_big), number=100)
2.0086487390001366
```

And see it scales not great:

```
>>> data_big = data_big * 100
>>> print(f'{len(data_big):,d}')
11,000,000
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : with_unzip(data_big), number=10) # made number smaller
27.03781091399992
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : with_loop(data_big), number=10) # made number smaller
17.5005345510001
```

This is probably because `a, b, c = zip(*whatever)` ultimately does two-passes over the data, because unpacking the arguments into `zip` isn't free. You can really see the effect of this if we micro-optimize the looping version by caching the `.append` method resolution:

```
>>> def with_loop_microp(data):
...     a = []
...     b = []
...     c = []
...     a_append = a.append
...     b_append = b.append
...     c_append = c.append
...     for i, (j, k) in data:
...         a_append(i)
...         b_append(j)
...         c_append(k)
...     return a,b,c
...
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda : with_loop_microp(data_big), number=10) # made number smaller
10.746374250000144
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is:

```py
a, bc = map(list, zip(*data))
b, c = map(list, zip(*bc))
```

If you don't care that `a`, `b` and `c` will be tuples, you can also use:

```py
a, bc = zip(*data)
b, c = zip(*bc)
```

Comment: No need to use `list` but I like this

Comment: Nice catch @juanpa.arrivillaga! I have adapted my code to reflect your comment.

Comment: Actually `map` is also not really necessary. This could become quite a neat answer by being `a, bc = zip(*data) ; b, c = zip(*bc)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Tomerikoo! I have added it to my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
a, b, c = zip(*[[x[0], x[1][0], x[1][1]] for x in data])
```